# Line spacing between selected rows in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice-writer, line-spacing

Line spacing seems to be a paragraph specific setting in OpenOffice Writer. When I try to choose 2 lines and I change the line spacing, all the paragraph gets changed. How can I get the line spacing to be effective only between the selected rows?

Comment: I see that you have tagged this as openoffice-writer, but ti took me a second to realize that. You might consider being more specific about the software you are asking about in your question body.

Comment: Thanks, I added OpenOffice Writer. I assume there is similar problem for Microsoft Word as well, but I'm only interested in solution for OpenOffice Writer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this unless you fake the look. You can't set a different line spacing to specific lines inside a paragraph.

What you could try is enter a new line character at the end of the line just before the different spacing is to be applied with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will create a new paragraph for you. Apply the line spacing to that portion of text.

Keep in mind that the line spacing of the last line will push out the next paragraph accordingly.

Comment: This is how I have done it. It's just weird that you need to end some sentences without a dot.